# Clipboard.JS How to make the new string to front with 'success' event?

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I'm using the 'success' event to change the button text after someone have clicked it.

The original button text is in `span` and it will be covered by the animation, so I use CSS rule:
`z-index` and `color` to make the text visible and to the front.

The problem is the text will be hidden under the animation after the function is invoked because the new string is not in `span` anymore.

How do I make the new string in `span` so the CSS will still work to make it front?

Below is my code:

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyElement')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    let oldtext = e.trigger.textContent
    e.trigger.textContent = 'Copied!'
    setTimeout(() => e.trigger.textContent = oldtext, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 330px;
}

.copyElement {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.Medium {
  width: 210px;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.Small {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 21px 0 18px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.ButtonMain {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.ButtonMain::before,
.ButtonMain::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ButtonMain span {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.ButtonMain:hover span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.RedRevealEffect::before {
  content: '';
  background: #ef476f;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
}

.RedRevealEffect:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Small"
  data-clipboard-text="123"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Medium"
  data-clipboard-text="456"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Big"
  data-clipboard-text="789"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the button's text lies inside the `span`. Use `querySelector('span')` to change the span's text

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyElement')

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    let span = e.trigger.querySelector('span')
    let oldtext = span.textContent
    span.textContent = 'Copied!'
    setTimeout(() => span.textContent = oldtext, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 330px;
}

.copyElement {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Big {
  width: 257px;
  padding: 33px 0 30px 0;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.Medium {
  width: 210px;
  padding: 27px 0 24px 0;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.Small {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 21px 0 18px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.ButtonMain {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}

.ButtonMain::before,
.ButtonMain::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ButtonMain span {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.ButtonMain:hover span {
  color: #000;
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.RedRevealEffect::before {
  content: '';
  background: #ef476f;
  width: 120%;
  left: -10%;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1, 0.8, 1);
}

.RedRevealEffect:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Small"
  data-clipboard-text="123"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Medium"
  data-clipboard-text="456"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>
<button
  class="copyElement ButtonMain RedRevealEffect Big"
  data-clipboard-text="789"
>
  <span>Take Me There</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.8/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```